# R: "Fuzzy Match" and "Between" Statements

Tags: sql, r, join, data-manipulation, fuzzy-logic

I am working with the R Programming Language. I have the following tables (note: all variables appear as "Factors"):

```
table_1 = data.frame(id = c("123", "123", "125", "C125-B"), 
date_1 = c("2010-01-31","2010-01-31", "2016-01-31", "2018-01-31" ))

table_1$id = as.factor(table_1$id)
table_1$date_1 = as.factor(table_1$date_1)

table_2 = data.frame(id = c("5123", "123 A", "125", "125"), 
date_2 = c("2009-01-31","2010-01-31", "2010-01-31", "2010-01-31" ),
date_3 = c("2011-01-31","2010-01-31", "2020-01-31", "2020-01-31" ))


table_2$id = as.factor(table_2$id)
table_2$date_2 = as.factor(table_2$date_2)
table_2$date_3 = as.factor(table_2$date_3)


> table_1
      id     date_1
1    123 2010-01-31
2    123 2010-01-31
3    125 2016-01-31
4 C125-B 2018-01-31

 table_2
     id     date_2     date_3
1  5123 2009-01-31 2011-01-31
2 123 A 2010-01-31 2010-01-31
3   125 2010-01-31 2020-01-31
4   125 2010-01-31 2020-01-31
```

I am trying to "join" (e.g. inner join) this tables on the following conditions:

**1)** `if table_1$id "fuzzy equal" table_2$id`

AND

**2)** `if table_1$date BETWEEN(table_2$date_2,table_2$date_3)`

I tried to write the following code in R to do this:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
stringdist_inner_join(table_1, table_2,
                      by ="id", distance_col = NULL)
```

**Question:** But I am not sure if the `stringdist_inner_join` function can accommodate this kind of "between" logic.

Can someone please show me how to do this? Are there any other methods to accomplish this in R?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the intention behind making your dates into factors? Won't that make it harder to compare them chronologically?

Comment: @ Jon Spring: Thank you for your reply! The dates in my original set are factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? We could do the stringdist_inner_join and filter afterwards if the dates are stored as dates. This should be plenty performant for most data, and if not you should probably use data.table instead of fuzzyjoin.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)
table_1$date_1 = as.Date(table_1$date_1)
table_2$date_2 = as.Date(table_2$date_2)
table_2$date_3 = as.Date(table_2$date_3)
stringdist_inner_join(table_1, table_2, by = "id", max_dist = 2) %>%
  filter(date_1 >= date_2, date_1 <= date_3)


   id.x     date_1  id.y     date_2     date_3
1   123 2010-01-31  5123 2009-01-31 2011-01-31
2   123 2010-01-31 123 A 2010-01-31 2010-01-31
3   123 2010-01-31   125 2010-01-31 2020-01-31
4   123 2010-01-31   125 2010-01-31 2020-01-31
5   123 2010-01-31  5123 2009-01-31 2011-01-31
6   123 2010-01-31 123 A 2010-01-31 2010-01-31
7   123 2010-01-31   125 2010-01-31 2020-01-31
8   123 2010-01-31   125 2010-01-31 2020-01-31
9   125 2016-01-31   125 2010-01-31 2020-01-31
10  125 2016-01-31   125 2010-01-31 2020-01-31
```

Comment: @ Jon Spring: Thank you for your answer! Can you please explain why "max_dist  = 2"? Thank you!

Comment: Why is the font green?

Comment: I'm just making a guess at a good value for your data (it's also the default so not necessary to specify).

Comment: @jay.sf, I have no idea! I didn't think I had done anything different, curious what triggered that.

Comment: @ Jon Spring: If you have time, can you please take a look at some of my other questions?

Comment: (bountied) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70231544/re-writing-fuzzy-join-functions-from-r-to-sql

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70297569/r-running-dplyr-statements-over-sqlquery

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70297680/r-remove-duplicate-columns-via-sqlquery